# Linux execline scripting

Tags: linux, scripting, execline

So I need to benchmark a program that I wrote, and for some reason, my professor asked to benchmark it against an [execline](http://skarnet.org/software/execline/) script. After 3 hours, I still have no clue how to do execline scripting. could someone please transfer this bash script into execline script ?

```
cat f1 | sort | tr a-z A-Z >f2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/command/execlineb

pipeline { cat f1 } pipeline { sort } redirfd -w 1 f2 tr a-z A-Z
```

as you can see here: http://skarnet.org/software/execline/pipeline.html
and here: http://skarnet.org/software/execline/redirfd.html